# Adding points only to selected levels of a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
> glimpse(pd)
Observations: 340
Variables: 4
$ gene_id  <fctr> T03F1.6, T01B11.2, F40D4.13, F38B6.4, F10F2....
$ inter    <fctr> K9me3, K9me3, K9me3, K9me3, K9me3, K9me3, K9...
$ genotype <fctr> 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641,...
$ value    <dbl> 0.88733425, -0.47734512, 0.16116906, -0.40425...
```

and plotting code:

```
p4 <- ggplot(pd) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=inter, 
                     y=value, 
                     col=inter, shape=genotype, alpha=genotype), size = 3) +
                 scale_color_manual(values = cc, name = ' ') +
                 scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.6,1)) +
                 myggplot.y0 +
                 theme(legend.position="bottom") +
                 myggplot.blankXtext +
                 facet_wrap(~gene_id, ncol=2) +
        guides(color=guide_legend(title='')) 
p4
```

[image]

I'd like to summarize the round shaped points by a boxplot (at each dodging level), but keep the triangle shaped points (which only appear in the last two 'levels') as separate 'points' overlayed on the boxplot.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the data to reproduce the `data.frame`:

```
> dput(pd)
structure(list(gene_id = structure(c(8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 10L, 9L, 7L), .Label = c("F10F2.2", "F21E9.3", "F38B6.4", 
"F40D4.13", "K10D3.6", "T01B11.2", "T02E9.2", "T03F1.6", "T04A8.5", 
"T21F4.1"), class = "factor"), inter = structure(c(16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("K27me0", 
"K27me1", "K27me2", "K27me3", "K36me0", "K36me1", "K36me2", "K36me3", 
"K4me0", "K4me1", "K4me2", "K4me3", "K9me0", "K9me1", "K9me2", 
"K9me3"), class = "factor"), genotype = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("N2", "641"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.887334249026434, 
-0.47734511528238, 0.161169059129204, -0.40425962740708, -0.448772664830352, 
-2.54043183911831, 0.147633437904588, -0.331999887972573, 0.168821284679471, 
0.627281852456115, 0.0785458811781217, -0.635417116680447, 1.95039267129571, 
-0.461389508271182, -0.332495133573183, -1.07629215381253, -0.715262085650234, 
0.380580191285256, -0.384548303669202, -0.492327117463121, -0.0635811095948338, 
-0.137169496659571, 0.869104975820394, -0.124274416739264, -0.00837899314070789, 
-0.531344335277651, -0.526039923426319, 0.157981596945951, -0.0613955127076382, 
-0.389835314108788, 2.69392711479386, 0.126789590130756, 0.467843320254945, 
0.119956248487539, -0.932684036187982, 1.06163513421864, -1.15599025769053, 
0.501998795474814, 0.547724207589878, 0.208660744829548, 2.39652396988934, 
-0.113536659142323, 0.617602997781084, -0.0243661090708898, -0.931766154859557, 
0.84708053705325, -0.302694166168958, 0.242295516669482, 0.362144368539548, 
0.143166134234178, 2.10369156882084, 0.460380422671629, -0.0118030947996877, 
-1.30190938551855, -0.944990285797225, 1.78280710295825, -0.634879160361434, 
0.633411617712061, -0.323643001568312, -0.352447999186893, 0.27261554500361, 
-0.184793596205417, -0.785654613201974, -0.380434850649155, -0.116175416888516, 
0.391864521424546, 0.288960168023483, -0.0808022493276015, -0.624387637961664, 
-0.652297254014572, 1.75147794216705, -0.439685382191905, 0.150488781634707, 
-0.0336437864682964, -0.802955390112682, 1.06183416852385, -0.923263618312843, 
0.468046260016009, 0.286851381130517, 0.17305984039931, 1.75158852119529, 
-0.592564500094055, 0.248498177746989, -0.222638458602893, -0.720265703696414, 
0.72750611824884, -0.336818721832683, 0.511031230869627, 0.0430587972307137, 
0.0290598947165659, 0.886443959972121, -0.303364064568797, -0.277915654881935, 
-0.462931588140646, -0.512912057394122, 0.130398107823421, -0.410559505055534, 
-0.543074481188406, 0.223303098899384, -0.35597446101497, 0.584846557204577, 
-0.328552338525071, 0.39166741782988, -0.419624587301293, -0.417042458658473, 
-0.0500348090171157, 0.440292934053895, -0.0389439842100643, 
-0.192935439273113, -0.195280031711113, -0.330623439443579, 0.406193213631403, 
1.60465863614407, 0.488558950927488, 0.306422606850451, 0.0259842742803569, 
0.464781609520434, 0.382521939171359, -0.697256999098308, 0.74469109948364, 
0.0564480245933332, 0.451572695093123, 1.65543142016647, 0.471407535866445, 
0.287994086588806, -0.589245829633368, 0.369581847988354, 0.597812561310243, 
-0.607302119427235, 0.9696199804852, 0.153586315079381, -0.619187466367118, 
0.656675901432987, -0.871392537978112, -0.311214917388622, -0.923682063590928, 
-0.323604082561573, -0.693266286639908, 0.0290631195420703, -0.291795800840029, 
-0.0916009854020086, -0.529683872226366, 0.341292466699543, -0.964841093192905, 
-0.349467794977152, -0.502029626725142, -0.254774675707687, -1.20345690995063, 
0.220507237168474, -0.954023439798044, 0.321770602015399, -0.726063502895515, 
0.28288258484054, -1.55107383696037, -0.366037696773723, -0.587999636824452, 
-1.35916629238201, -1.42792505502871, 1.05596729613068, -1.4153269555524, 
-0.0959965268426171, -0.581692078188237, 0.0216148704828045, 
-0.967560147159656, -0.406889554155961, -0.29013462836955, -0.272629044721009, 
-1.74574575300093, 0.409694897073192, -0.945248012942512, 0.488667747235731, 
-0.130769790765262, -0.245054023224077, -1.22641996252332, -0.42550379283728, 
-0.330755471294788, -1.49812536880092, -0.687381177317297, 0.506910130730609, 
-0.769620490644054, 0.0531265417354891, -0.665086454118599, 0.136193457296536, 
-0.62216089856077, -0.367848687570944, -0.164342714173533, -0.382590305354972, 
-0.874808163574018, 0.493411933475686, -0.37887729896755, -0.574238871100946, 
0.127741068021188, 3.86039295680539, 0.406874973642696, 0.018180549517699, 
-0.73164426806948, 0.10916295082713, 0.489171565128614, -0.63809359131097, 
0.012317883603111, -0.182079038293229, 0.0227150325950261, 3.68710015302125, 
0.455122847588301, 0.0235041737883517, -0.024393097564638, 0.41345288614306, 
0.969811866964937, -0.672585115335576, 0.331895771644743, -0.285694918186591, 
-0.711647452923045, 1.38434450822266, -0.523103532001491, -0.0893223046296763, 
-1.01365895485872, 0.0657806542743673, -1.39534058124217, -0.923222605651799, 
-1.39887741940789, -0.0952580333454192, -0.546574104718356, 1.46477855989728, 
-0.460227934172416, -0.240045678851763, -0.0111436043830646, 
0.0627986215438661, -0.251396685372123, -0.934093688281673, -1.05820277806975, 
0.556102701675237, -0.506831613088146, 0.134996075420438, -0.304509562226102, 
-0.530606844852739, -0.576258795363492, 0.558240796235196, 0.00141004667762168, 
-0.219444435445798, -0.537347914917884, 0.923884368998904, -0.425823765099706, 
0.402984847066973, -0.0138900208495514, -0.466549078530587, -0.0299175806841818, 
-0.198688733963097, 0.419444078428615, -0.416005826002221, -0.0406133025559159, 
-0.711562592297027, -0.00565350152856414, 4.54871285677085, 0.118779124267025, 
0.0139761953422664, -0.664583716722071, -0.743919010180514, 0.706218216909635, 
-0.683249460883233, 0.0605499462979795, -0.158429916510739, -0.222706230740269, 
4.71119851589582, 0.25500719760156, -0.0752734072712284, -0.795844146522265, 
0.178040897179368, 0.895173312761832, -1.03093515891618, -0.588056522862408, 
-0.281825764719025, -0.056228940433579, -0.313824928780573, -0.0917469172753451, 
-0.122912334871057, 0.712942661491444, -0.0416925666113199, -0.103626376180252, 
-0.123906792244526, -0.338488229262714, -0.285202171459416, -0.012465219280215, 
-0.140276363711298, -0.116007895520325, -0.111935190660002, 0.225067028104865, 
0.435777323306682, -0.107111364797968, -0.0547435542980068, -0.245852927399465, 
-0.646765570905925, -0.574523578850278, 1.23916851484567, -0.756916946637266, 
-0.442286710512833, -0.653558388340836, -0.104749483441292, -0.0656026501027611, 
-0.611101876494586, -1.24462228141138, -1.08065682436839, -0.11380843108228, 
4.76147315049708, 0.0164152091429139, -0.0182056738105381, -0.385790482896067, 
1.20308626895301, -0.241046175728772, 0.0412353010350772, -1.37886106242171, 
-0.652945846253202, 0.0284072616942028, 0.780335178644036, -0.644783275438296, 
-0.319045839781824, 1.57554487548949, -0.428706034693799, -0.350808314840347, 
-0.24066856927377, -1.04530746723789, -0.240526163518468, -0.437546091131759, 
3.36251366149142, -0.101287227327982, -0.149730531058178, -2.05718920626846, 
0.316516294262123, 0.798192960479417, -1.0788450246926, -0.0806608802523838, 
-0.670068360692003, -0.419448747866297, 6.36279926782848, -0.0378872162137345, 
-0.692973015966929, -1.31677539848766, -0.576391545143803, 1.42209640226752, 
-1.13065080356991, 0.26979963818752)), .Names = c("gene_id", 
"inter", "genotype", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-340L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subsets of the data for the separate geoms:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=inter, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = subset(pd, genotype == "N2")) +
  geom_point(data = subset(pd, genotype == "641"), aes(col=inter), size = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~gene_id, ncol=2) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title=''))
```

Note that a bunch of you plotting code isn't actually reproducible since it relies on objects such as `myggplot.y0`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for! I thought about subsetting, but didn't manage to do it correctly.